# Do I really need foreach loop for this?! (foreach probably overkilling)

Tags: sharepoint, loops, foreach

I need to get GUID of an item. I know the SiteURL, List Name and Item Name. How do I get guid of this item insead to using splistitem li in list.items and loop through each item (if li.name==myitemname then assign strguid=li.uniqueid.tostring()

Is there a way not to use foreach loop since I know the name of the item? This will save time to loop throught items.

Comment: SPList.GetItems(SPQuery). I guess I need to construct my query. But it uses the listcollection so again going though everything... hmm

Comment: Name? Do you mean Title?

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating a spquery on your unique item in splistcollection you would be returned only one element which you can obtain without foreach

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteURL))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList apps = web.GetList(web.Url + "/Lists/MyList");
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = String.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='String'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where>", _title);
                    items = apps.GetItems(query);
                    if(items.Count > 0)
                       {
                         Guid id = items[0].UniqueId;
                       }
                }
            }
```

Comment: qry.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'"; or 
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";

Answer (score 0):

Works but I have 11 files and they all have the same file name "license.txt" and they are in the same document library. 1 file "license.txt" is under the root document library and other 10 in 10 different folders within a document library. so what if i am looking for the license.txt file that's in Demo folder?

This code works but only finds license.txt under the root.

`private void btnGetFileGuid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://www.abc.com/sites/Software"))
 {
  using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
  {
   SPList spList = web.Lists["Auto Cad"];
   string fileName = "license.txt";
   SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
   query.Query="<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /><Value Type='Text'>" + fileName + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
   SPListItemCollection items = spList.GetItems(query);
   if (items.Count > 0)
   {
    Guid id = items[0].UniqueId;
    lblGuid.Text = id.ToString();
   }
  }
 }
}`

Comment: Has anyone able to solve this issue? I have more than 10 items in different folders within the same document library. It's not finding any one of them. I think it only works if the item is in the root of the doc lib and only counts this one item.

Answer (score 0):

Trying the following and it seems to be working.

```
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
```

or

```
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='RecursiveAll'";
```